# _token is present on the POST data but form fails with error: "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I know this topic has been discussed several times in SO but I've checked a tons of topics none seems to be like mine and so far what I have test is not fixing my issue. First thing I am using Symfony 3.2.4 with PHP 7.1.2.

I have the following code in my controller:

```
class QuoteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/quote/register")
     */
    public function registerAction()
    {
        $entity = new Quote();
        $form   = $this->createForm(QuoteType::class, $entity);

        return $this->render(
            'QuoteBundle:Quote:register.html.twig',
            ['entity' => $entity, 'form' => $form->createView()]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/quote/save", name="save-quote")
     */
    public function saveAction()
    {
        $entity = new Quote();
        $form   = $this->createForm(QuoteType::class, $entity);

        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            dump($form->getData());
        } else {
            dump($_POST);
            dump($form->getErrors());
        }

        die();
    }
}
```

This is how my `QuoteType` looks like:

```
class QuoteType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('schneider_quote_id')
            ->add('agreement_number')
            ->add('quote_creation_source')
            ->add('quote_status')
            ->add('distributor_id')
            ->add('start_date', DateType::class)
            ->add('end_date', DateType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Create Post']);
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Quote::class,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'quote';
    }
}
```

And finally this is how my template register looks like:

```
{% block body %}
    {{ form_start(form, {'action': path('save-quote'), 'method': 'POST'}) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form._token) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

But when I send the form I got the error:

> The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.

If you notice I've `dump()` the `$_POST` data among the form errors and this is the result:

```
dump($_POST);
array:1 [▼
  "quote" => array:9 [▼
    "schneider_quote_id" => "100"
    "agreement_number" => "100"
    "quote_creation_source" => "sdasdasd"
    "quote_status" => "sadsad"
    "distributor_id" => "2"
    "start_date" => array:3 [▶]
    "end_date" => array:3 [▶]
    "save" => ""
    "_token" => "bSuU7h7rDR-_FkEGZ3zS60OtIofs_1bAi-J-YdCtxlM"
  ]
]

dump($form->getErrors());
FormErrorIterator {#32 ▼
  -form: Form {#672 ▼
    -config: FormBuilder {#673 ▶}
    -parent: null
    -children: OrderedHashMap {#674 ▶}
    -errors: array:1 [▼
      0 => FormError {#625 ▶}
    ]
    -submitted: true
    -clickedButton: SubmitButton {#787 ▶}
    -modelData: Quote {#444 ▶}
    -normData: Quote {#444 ▶}
    -viewData: Quote {#444 ▶}
    -extraData: []
    -transformationFailure: null
    -defaultDataSet: true
    -lockSetData: false
  }
  -errors: array:1 [▼
    0 => FormError {#625 ▼
      -message: "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form."
      #messageTemplate: "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form."
      #messageParameters: []
      #messagePluralization: null
      -cause: null
      -origin: Form {#672}
    }
  ]
}
```

The question is why if the `_token` is present on the POST data is not being read by Symfony properly?

I have read the docs for [CSRF Protection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html#csrf-protection) from [The Form Components](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html) and I am confused now, maybe things has changed in Symfony 3 and I am not aware. Do I need this piece of code in my controller|form somehow?

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Forms;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Csrf\CsrfExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenStorage\SessionTokenStorage;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenGenerator\UriSafeTokenGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManager;

// create a Session object from the HttpFoundation component
$session = new Session();

$csrfGenerator = new UriSafeTokenGenerator();
$csrfStorage = new SessionTokenStorage($session);
$csrfManager = new CsrfTokenManager($csrfGenerator, $csrfStorage);

$formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
    // ...
    ->addExtension(new CsrfExtension($csrfManager))
    ->getFormFactory();
```

Why I am missing here?

Comment: Are your site connections under https? If yes, you have to be sure to have the parameter `cookie_secure` (under `session` section of the `config.yml`) set on `true`, otherwise all csfr tokens will be invalidated.

Comment: @gp_sflover no, that's not the case unfortunately

Comment: Replace "{{ form_row(form._token) }}" with "{{ form_rest(form) }}"

Comment: @pogeybait already tried, same issue something weird is happening there and I haven't a clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few headaches I finally found where the problem was coming from. This is how my `session` section looks like at my `config.yml`:

```
session:
    storage_id: session.storage.php_bridge
    handler_id: ~
    save_path:  ~
```

Changing the above config to this one:

```
session:
    handler_id: session.handler.native_file
    save_path:  ~
```

So apparently `~` doesn't set the default `handler_id` at all.